# Problems with e.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

I have problems using preventDefault. The problem is that this piece of code works fine (it prevents the click everytime and I get the alert):

```
$("#vnesi").click(function (e) {
            $.post("/VnosPrijavnica/PreveriVnose", $("#kriteriji").serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data != "ok")
                    alert(data);

            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

But this doesn't (nothig happens, if data is either "ok" or not):

```
        $("#vnesi").click(function (e) {
            $.post("/VnosPrijavnica/PreveriVnose", $("#kriteriji").serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data != "ok"){
                    alert(data);
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

        });
```

And also one more question. What is the best way to debug javascript in Firefox 4 (or any other browser but I prefer Firefox 4)?

**Update**

Thanks for your answers. How can I preventDefault() if I want it to act like in the second piece of code? I want e.preventDefault() to execute only if the data != "ok".

Comment: user , firebug is the best to debug.

Comment: Find out what is happening. Do you use PHP for the backend? Perhaps you get an error there.

Comment: i also think firebug  is the best

Comment: @kobe & user: Or if you use Chrome. Just use Chrome's developer tools. Both are great tools.

Comment: Also always use curly braces for your IF statements (even if it is only 1 line).  :-)

Comment: How can I preventDefault() if I want it to act like in the second piece of code? I want e.preventDefault() to execute only if the data != "ok".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calling `e.preventDefault()` in an asynchronous callback. The event handler will have completed before you prevented the event.

Basically you cannot change the event in the callback because the event has completed. You need to handle this differently (i.e. outside the callback).

```
$("#vnesi").click(function(e) {
    $.post("/VnosPrijavnica/PreveriVnose", $("#kriteriji").serialize(), function(data) {
        if (data != "ok") {
            alert(data);
        } else {
             // ajax post failed 
             // trigger the action of the event again. (form.submit ??)
        }
    });
    // prevent the default always
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

For debugging in firefox. Either use the in build tools (Ctrl+Shift+J) or [install firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Then use F12 to open firebug.

Answer (score 1):

user return false , it does both preventDefault and stopPropogation

you should do that in outerloop..

```
$("#vnesi").click(function (e) {
            $.post("/VnosPrijavnica/PreveriVnose", $("#kriteriji").serialize(), function (data) {
                if (data != "ok"){
                    alert(data);

                }
            });
          return false
        });
```

and to your other question , **firebug** is the best

Comment: That is not the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

hej user725912 the post call is async meaning that your not preventing the default action in time.

the async call returns after the default action has been done.

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` can be called anywhere in the scope of the event handler's function.  It can be the first or last line but it **cannot** be inside another function within it especially not in one that is being called asynchronously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It can be in another function. It just needs to be inside a synchronous function.