# event.preventDefault in async functions

Tags: javascript, async-await

Will it be possible to use event.preventDefault in an async function?

I am not sure because event.preventDefault must be called synchronously and async functions return promises.

```
self.oncontextmenu = async function(event) {
 event.preventDefault()
 //await whatever
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `preventDefault` async, because the event handling is fully synchronous. (similar question: [Problems with e.preventDefault()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100826) )

Comment: perhaps you should give a more concrete example of what you are trying to do. I'm not sure I understand your goal, and I have the impression you are mixing up things a bit. Also promise and async are two different things (though related)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is totally possible to call `preventDefault()` in an `async` event handler `function`. You only have to ensure to make the call before the first `await`, as otherwise the event already will have happened when the function resumes. The event flow will continue and not wait for the promise that the event handler returns.

Comment: (There are experiments with "[ExtendableEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent)s" that can be made to wait for *some* promises, but they're not DOM events and they don't have to do anything with `async function`s)

Comment: Well, there goes my super duper idea for using an (asynchronous) Bootstrap modal instead of a (synchronous) confirm().

Comment: @RonInbar Depending on what event you are trying to prevent, you may just always call `preventDefault()` (as the default action should not happen right now), show your asynchronous modal, and when the user confirms that (by a different event) you can trigger the original action directly.